# Miniconda and Git

Tags: github, miniconda

Good day. have git installed and conifgured as per normal. Using Miniconda...however when pushing local repo to git - am unable to. My question when using miniconda must git be installed in everyone project environment using `conda install -c anaconda git`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late response on this matter. Since 2020 - git decided to remove "master" from its naming convention and replaced with "main". However "brew install git" or using git with miniconda still references the "master" as a branch. And this is what i noticed the mistake was. Anyways - went into Github and changed the branch name - "main" back to "master". And now seemingly all is fine. My question though - how would one then configure homebrew/anconda local settings so that it references the new naming convention. Or does one simply switch between master and main locally?